# scipy spatial to get the distance from a 3D point and an array of 3D points

Tags: python, scipy-spatial

**Problem**

I have a location `point = [(580991.4677, 4275267.6366, 192.2548)]`
I want to calculate the distance from `point` to the nearest location in `X` and insert it to the point. This means `dist` will be something like this: 
`[(580991.4677, 4275267.6366, 192.2548, <distance value>)]` The matching point is not important, but the distance value is.

**Sample data: X**

```
[(580991.4344, 4275267.6452, 192.3217),
 (580991.4369, 4275267.4457, 192.3945),
 (580991.4375, 4275267.4929, 192.396),
 (580991.4599, 4275267.5186, 192.3361),
 (580991.4644, 4275267.5889, 192.2631)]
```

**Script**

So far I can calculate the n-distances. But this is calculating the distances between the points in the array X, not in comparison to the point object.

```
import scipy.spatial.distance
dist = scipy.spatial.distance.pdist(X, metric='euclidean')
```

**Result**

```
array([0.21238253, 0.16948566, 0.12994295, 0.08662361, 0.04722764,
   0.09619756, 0.19628665, 0.06892213, 0.16613856, 0.10144624])
```

Any pointers?

Comment: if this did the trick, would you please mark it as the accepted answer for me? :)

Answer (score 2):

Well from the docs: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html

`scipy.spatial.distance.pdist` calculates the distance between each pair of points in a single list.

If you want to calculate the distance between `point` and every entry in `X`, you probably want `cdist` which does the following:

> Compute distance between each pair of the two collections of inputs.

so you would call: `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(point, X)`